# Hide mergeinfo files from TortoiseSVN commit dialog

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is there a way to hide files from my commit dialog that don't have any actual changes, but only mergeinfo changes.

I like to see what I've changed and I can't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the column header. Then select the columns `text status` and `property status`.

Now you can sort by those columns: if there's only a change in the `mergeinfo` property, the `property status` column will show `modified`, but the `text status` column will show `normal`. Only if the `text status` columns shows something else than `normal`, there's a change to the content of the file.

Comment: I already had those columns visible. I also found the "Status" column, which consolidates those 2 columns in to one. I was really hoping for some way to not show the files where only properties have changed and just show the files that I'd actually changed the contents of.